# Find the principal solutions of the trigonometric equation $\cos x-\sin x+\sin 2x+3\cos2x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am unable to simplify the expression. If I simplify the double angles, it leaves me with a nasty expression, 
$\cos x-\sin x+2\sin x\cos x+6\cos^2 x-2=0$. What do I do next. Some hints, please. Also, is there some **elegant** solution? Thanks!

Comment: Try the double-angle formula.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did. It isn't solvable after a few steps.

Comment: Could you please show your work on the double angle formula?

Comment: Now, you could separate out the $\sin(x)$, square both sides, let $y=\cos(x)$ and then hope for a solution to the resulting degree 4 equation.  The solutions are then very easy, $1/2$ is a double root and the rest is the quadratic formula.

Comment: $t=\tan \frac x2$ also gives a quartic

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $a = \cos x$ and $b = \sin x$ so that you get $$a - b + 2ab + 6a^2 - 2 = 0 \iff (2a-1)(3a + b + 2) = 0$$

One solution is already apparent, $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$, can you work out the others?

Answer (score 2):

Observe:
$$
\cos x-\sin x+2\sin x\cos x+6\cos^2 x-2=(\sin x)(2\cos x-1)+(2\cos x-1)(3\cos x+2)=(\sin x+3\cos x-2)(2\cos x-1).
$$
Therefore, $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$ is a solution.
The solutions to $\sin x+3\cos x+2=0$ are less pleasant, but one can solve $\sin x=-2-3\cos x$, square both sides and solve, using the quadratic formula for $\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

I pick the solution by Michael Burr and Zain Patel and focus on the roots of $f(x)=3\cos x + \sin x +2$:

using this [page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin%28x%29_%2B_b_cos%28x%29) you may write:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sqrt{10}\sin\Big(x+\arcsin\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\Big)+2
\end{align}
hence the roots are $x_k=-\arcsin\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}-\arcsin\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{5}}+2k\pi$

Comment: Good job! This is a nice follow-up to our solutions. :-)

Comment: Thanks! you two did the main work :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have $\cos x-\sin x+\sin 2x+3\cos 2x+1=0$. Or $\sin x-\sin 2x=\cos x+3\cos 2x+1$. Or $\sin x(1-2\cos x)=\cos x+6\cos^2x-2$.

Either $\cos x =1/2$ or $\sin x=((6\cos^2x+\cos x-2)/(1-2\cos x))$. Or $\sin x=-3\cos x-2$. Squaring we get $10\cos^2x-12\cos x+3=0$. Thus $\cos x=((6\pm \sqrt{6})/(10))$.